# drupal 7 field.tpl if this field is empty show this

Tags: drupal-7

I have a node that has two author fields. I have a link to the comments section with comment that is displayed after the second author's name. So if there is an author name in both fields, I get the "# of comments" link.  If there is no second author, the "# of comments" link does not show (because the field does not display). I am using field.tpl.php

I think the way to do this is one of these ways:
1) on first field say, "If second field is empty show "# of comments"
or
2) on second field say, "if this field is not empty show "# of comments" (and there will be a "# of comments" link with no conditions that will show if the field is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:
In the field.tpl.php for the first_author_name I added the code below:

```
<?php if (empty($element['#object']->field_second_author_name)) : ?> 

<div class="comment-add">

<?php

  if ($element['#object']->comment_count == 0) { 
      $output = t('Add a comment'); } 
      else { 
      $output = format_plural($element['#object']->comment_count, '1 Comment', '@count Comments'); }

      print '<span class="comment-add-pipe">|</span> <a href="#comments">' . $output . '</a>';

?>
</div>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

The **$element['#object']->field_second_author_name** checks another field to see if it is empty or not. If it **IS** empty (no second author), it adds the comment_count after the first author name.

I also have the code for comment_count in the field.tpl for the second author, so if there **IS** a second author, then the comment_count shows up after the second author name.